# Intellij Idea run configuration with ember.js on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ember.js, intellij-idea

I am having a problem with the run configuration of ember on intellij idea on ubuntu 14.

I have installed ember using npm and I have followed a tutorial on my teacher's site on how to correctly configure intellij to use both maven and ember. I had no problem configuring the first part (maven), however at the second part, which was basically the same, I couldn't find the file he was refering to. Here is the picture:
[tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrTbM.png)

And here is the error:
[error]

```
Error: No ember-cli-build.js found. Please see the transition guide: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#user-content-brocfile-transition.
at CoreObject.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:56:13)
at CoreObject.module.exports.Task.extend.init (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:89:10)
at CoreObject.superWrapper [as init] (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/core-object/lib/assign-properties.js:32:18)
at CoreObject.Class (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:32:33)
at CoreObject.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/build.js:15:19)
at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/commands/build.js:32:24
at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:331:11
at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

Could you please help me find the file he was referring to in the tutorial (since "usr/bin" doesn't have any "ember" files)?

New error about permissions:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5odQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a brocfile.js in your project? If so, rename it to ember-cli-build... Apparently you installed a newer version of ember... You might want to re-run `ember init`

Have a look at https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#user-content-brocfile-transition as well for more information.

Depending on how you installed ember/ember-cli it would lie under (if you don't use nvm):
`~/.npm/`

or 
in your project structure:

`<project_dir>/node_modules` and `<project_dir>/bower_components`

Comment: I have tried using ember init from the command line on the webapp folder and it finished without any errors. After that I have changed the ember program path to:
/[project_name]/exam-web/src/main/webapp/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember.

Now it gives me an error about permission, which I will link to in the main post.

Comment: I have run a chmod command on ember from my path and the next error I get:
You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the build command.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't initialize ember project. Run `ember init` in `webapp` directory